# Copyright expiration on a translated work

Tags: copyright, public-domain

I am writing a video game, which I intend to sell (so it is not free to download), and would like to include a full version of a short story accessible within the game. The story was published in 1939, but in Spanish, and the publication of the English translation was in 1962.

Am I legally allowed to include the English Translation of the work within the game in its entirety, as in anyone who purchases the game will be able to read the work?

Comment: Which do you want to include the Spanish or English version? The English version is almost certainly still under copyright. In what countries where the two version published?

Comment: sorry, the english version. the english would either be the UK or US, I'm not sure.

Comment: This is an interesting duration of copyright question...can you phrase it so it doesn't look like a request for legal advice (i.e. a more general question focusing on commercially using the full text of a story with those publication dates).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If both works are public domain, yes. If not, you would need the copyright holder's permission.

It is possible that the original work is public domain depending on where it was first published and when the author died. If it was published in Spain and the author died before 1956 it is public domain (life + 60 years), however, if it were published in Mexico then it is public domain if the author died before 1944 (life + 50 years) but not after because the law changed to make it life + 100 years. If it was first published in the USA then things are **really** complicated. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries%27_copyright_lengths

However, even if the original is public domain the translation is almost certainly not. You could, in that case, translate it yourself (or commission a translation) but you couldn't use the 1960s one.